# Suddenly error on Excel Web Access web part

Tags: error, excel-web-access-webpart

I had some real nice Excel Web Access web parts going. Without any clear cause I suddenly get an error message, stating the file cannot be openened due to worksheet protection. It supposedly prevents the web part to access the source file. However, I have checked over and over but I have (and never had) sheet protection enabled on the sheets involved.

So I have no idea why the web parts suddenly stopped working correctly. Strange thing is, only one of the web parts does still work but the source is a different Excel file. I just don't get it.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found: a different sheet in the same Excel file was protected. This caused the problem. Strange though, as it was not the file the web part was directed to. Anyhow, case closed.